後 ways of readings (ato vs ushiro)
I'll split it into two questions:
the first one is about "after", the second one is about "behind"

if I want to say - in an hour - that will be 一時後に行きます　(ichi jikan go ni ikimasu), so if there is の　between 後　and time marker its gonna be ato? 食事の後　(shokuji no ato). is my position correct?
its about behind. I found this information: ato - if it is behind the back of something that is moving - 車は自転車の後に行っています(The car is driving behind the bicycle.)。　and ushiro is for for a stationary object - 車は自転車の後ろにあります (The car is located (is standing) behind the bicycle.)




if I want to say - in an hour - that will be 一時後に行きます　(ichi jikan go ni ikimasu), so if there is の　between 後　and time marker its gonna be ato? 食事の後　(shokuji no ato). is my position correct?


Yes, basically. The reading ご happens when attached to other words such as 一時間 後{ご}, 二年 後{ご}, 三週間 後{ご}, or even 食事 後{ご}. (Space added so that furigana displays only on 後). If you choose to add の, then it will become read as 後{あと}. 一時間の後{あと}, 二年の後{あと}, 三週間の後{あと}, or 食事の後{あと}
There is an exception to this, which is the term その後, which can either be その後{あと} or その後{ご}, and the meaning changes a bit. その後{あと} is the point of time immediately after the event, so like

まずは宿題を終わらせたい。その後{あと}遊びに行かない？ I wanna first do my homework, After that let's hangout ?

その後{ご} means something like "ever after", so it refers to the entire timeline after a certain event.

1912年、清朝は覆滅しました。その後{ご}、中国は共和国になりました。 In 1912, the Qing dynasty fell. Ever after, China became a republic.



its about behind. I found this information: ato - if it is behind the back of something that is moving - 車は自転車の後に行っています(The car is driving behind the bicycle.)。　and ushiro is for for a stationary object - 車は自転車の後ろにあります (The car is located (is standing) behind the bicycle.)


Ushiro is always written as 後{うし}ろ, with the ろ written out, so when you see a text you're sure to know if it's read as うしろ or not.
As for you're question, あと is after/behind on a sequential order, be that time or traffic or a number sequence.

「五」は「四」の後{あと}に来る

In your example, 車は自転車の後に行っています is あと because the car is sequentially behind/after the bike.
For, 後ろ it's like someone/something's "back" or "backside". Hiding behind someone's back is "誰かの後ろに隠れる" and never "誰かのあとに隠れる", unless this is a hide-and-seek game where your turn to hide is sequentially behind/after another person's turn to hide. As for motion... that's not deterministic. I can also use 後ろ for motion, like そいつの後ろについて行こう！　"Let's follow that guy's back!" Here, 後ろ just means the guy's "back(side)" and motion does not determine the use of うしろ/あと. Their meanings do.
